# Predict future values Excel

Tags: excel, data-analysis, forecasting

In the image below I have a sample of software usage reported on the 1st of each month. I need to do a predictive analysis and make a prediction on future usage trends.

I have been looking into forecast functions but can't seem to figure out how to apply this to my data.

[image]

Comment: You want [`FORECAST.LINEAR()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forecast-and-forecast-linear-functions-50ca49c9-7b40-4892-94e4-7ad38bbeda99)

Comment: How would that apply to my data, which values

FORECAST.LINEAR(x, known_y's, known_x's)

Comment: Your x would be the future date.  Your known y would be if the values in B and C and your known x would be the dates in A.  You would only include the data that is already set in those known x and y as they are the only ones known.  You would have one formula for each column of known y.  do not use both columns in the same formula

Comment: B and C are independent. I need a prediction on B separate to C. Would an AverageIF function suffice?

Comment: IF you think that is a better predicter of your data.  If you have no growth year to year than that would be fine.  If you have growth then you would want to use forcast.

Comment: I need forecast I just can't figure out which formula applies

Comment: You will need to explain more, including the formula you tried for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forecast-ets-function-15389b8b-677e-4fbd-bd95-21d464333f41

forecast.ets is what you need here.